# Data Set for Mankiw, Romer, and Weil 1992

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, solow, replication

I am trying to replicate the results of Mankiw, Romer and Weil 1992, and cannot seem to find the original data.

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen the GitHub Project [Replicating Mankiw, Romer and Weil 1992](https://github.com/HariharanJayashankar/mrw1992)? It seems to have both the data and a replication of the original results.

For the curious, the paper is [A Contribution to the Empirics of Economic Growth](https://academic.oup.com/qje/article-abstract/107/2/407/1838296).
Abstract:

> This paper examines whether the Solow growth model is consistent with
>   the international variation in the standard of living. It shows that
>   an augmented Solow model that includes accumulation of human as well
>   as physical capital provides an excellent description of the
>   cross-country data. The paper also examines the implications of the
>   Solow model for convergence in standards of living, that is, for
>   whether poor countries tend to grow faster than rich countries. The
>   evidence indicates that, holding population growth and capital
>   accumulation constant, countries converge at about the rate the
>   augmented Solow model predicts.